# Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context in k2

Tags: joomla, module, call, fatal-error, joomla-k2

this code call a field of a k2 component in joomla & show that. this code working in k2. but when i copy this code on another module to call that field give this error :
Im search 2 day in internet but ther are nothing:

```
<?php if($this->item->params->get('itemExtraFields') && count($this->item->extra_fields)): ?>
  <!-- Item extra fields -->
  <div class="itemExtraFields">
    <ul>
        <?php foreach ($this->item->extra_fields as $key=>$extraField): ?>
        <?php if($extraField->value != ''): ?>
        <li class="<?php echo ($key%2) ? "odd" : "even"; ?> type<?php echo ucfirst($extraField->type); ?> group<?php echo $extraField->group; ?>">
            <?php if($extraField->type == 'header'): ?>
            <h4 class="itemExtraFieldsHeader"><?php echo $extraField->name; ?></h4>
            <?php else: ?>
            <span class="itemExtraFieldsValue"><?php echo $extraField->value; ?></span>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </li>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        </ul>
  </div>
  <?php endif; ?>
```

this below code fore a module but when add to my code dont work :

```
<?php if($params->get('itemExtraFields') && count($item->extra_fields)): ?>
        <div class="moduleItemExtraFields">
            <b><?php echo JText::_('K2_ADDITIONAL_INFO'); ?></b>
            <ul>
              <?php foreach ($item->extra_fields as $extraField): ?>
                      <?php if($extraField->value): ?>
                      <li class="type<?php echo ucfirst($extraField->type); ?> group<?php echo $extraField->group; ?>">
                          <span class="moduleItemExtraFieldsLabel"><?php echo $extraField->name; ?></span>
                          <span class="moduleItemExtraFieldsValue"><?php echo $extraField->value; ?></span>
                          <div class="clr"></div>
                      </li>
                      <?php endif; ?>
              <?php endforeach; ?>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <?php endif; ?>

        <div class="clr"></div>
```

Comment: You paste it in a module or a component?

Comment: well, $this->item refers to an object in a component. You need to take a closer look if there is a K2 module that does that. Otherwise you need to include the k2 files.

Answer (score 3):

Why are you copying the the K2 component HTML into module. Use K2_content module, which solves all general purposes. It has also the extrafields display.

**If you still need it:**
Are you using the K2 component class for your new module?. If you did not prepare your class for your module in helper.php, then it will now work. To solve the purpose you need to copy the class in helper.php from K2 component into module's helper.php, however, this is a tough task getting the right code.

For line by line html, you can import the function from the class. Joomla has classes to import ready functions directly into template file (default.php). For this you have to:

1- Find the extrafield function from helper.php 
2- Import it into template file directly.

You can use directly as below where it works as CLASS::FUNCTION. In below example, it is coming from K2_content module.

```
 <?php foreach (modK2ContentHelper::getItems($item->extra_fields) as $extraField): ?>
```

Do not use below in module if not defined in your new module's xml file:

```
<?php if($params->get('itemExtraFields') && count($item->extra_fields)): ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

If your copying this code to another module.
That module is not a part of K2 (Separate module no relation with K2).Then calling this code will get error Bcoz the this here represent any of the K2 model,controller or view but in your module that may be module helper.

```
so the solution i suggest is make sure the required k2 files are included in the module.
and then call the $this-> with class name or create object.
```

This may solve your problem.